# How to define a static template variable inside a template class of the class type?

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have the following code

```
template<unsigned int n, class F, bool = std::floating_point<F>>
class Vector;

template<unsigned int n, class F>
class Vector<n, F, true> { //an n-dimensional vector
private:

   F* components;

public:
   Vector(F val) {
      components = ::new F[n];
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
         *(components + i) = val;
   }

   Vector(int index, F val) {
      components = ::new F[n];
      *(components + index) = val;
   }

   static const Vector ZERO;
   static const Vector UNIT;

   template<unsigned int m, bool = m <= n>
   static const Vector UNIT_M; //a Vector<n, F>, with only one component being equal to 1.0
};

template<unsigned int n, class F>
static const Vector<n, F> ZERO{0.0};

template<unsigned int n, class F>
static const Vector<n, F> UNIT{1.0};

/*
template<unsigned int n, unsigned int m, class F>
static const Vector<n, F> UNIT_M{m, 1.0}; //How do I include the template above?
*/
```

I had to declare the class Vector and then define it only when `std::floating_point<F>` was true. I want to do the same for UNIT_M only when `m <= n && m != 0` using the template. ZERO and UNIT work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a little bit another way. I propose to create a helper class Array in private section of class Vector. Class Array can be used in compile time. You can find my comments inside the example below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits> // In this example I used std::is_floating_point instead of std::floating_point

template<unsigned int n, class F, bool = std::is_floating_point<F>::value>
class Vector;

template<unsigned int n, class F>
class Vector<n, F, true> { //an n-dimensional vector
private:

   F* components = nullptr;
   
    // Class Array is needed in order to have analogue of class Vector which can be used in compile time.
    // Some constructors of class Vector can not be used in constant expressions because they refers to a result of 'operator new'.
    class Array {
    private:
        F components [n] = {0}; // initialize all elements to 0
    public:
        constexpr Array(const F &val) {
             for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 components[i] = val;
             }
        }
        constexpr Array(const size_t &index, const F &val) {
             components[index] = val;
        }
        constexpr ~Array() = default;
       
        constexpr Array(const Array & other) = delete;
        constexpr Array(Array && other) = delete;
        Array& operator=(const Array & other) = delete;
        Array& operator=(Array && other) = delete;
       
        const F & operator[](const size_t &i) const {
            return components[i];
        }
       
        Vector toVector() const {
            return Vector(*this);
        }
    };
   
    Vector(const Array &a) {
         components = ::new F[n];
         for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             components[i] = a[i];
         }
    }

public:
    Vector(const F &val) {
         components = ::new F[n];
         for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) { // it is better to use size_t because it can be 8 bytes if the program is compiled for 64-bit system
             components[i] = val;
         }
    }

    Vector(const size_t &index, const F &val) {
         components = ::new F[n];
         components[index] = val;
    }
   
    // Don't forget about copy constructor
    Vector(const Vector & other) {
         components = ::new F[n];
         for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
             components[i] = other.components[i];
         }
    }
   
    // Don't forget about move constructor
    Vector(Vector && other) : components(other.components) {
         other.components = nullptr;
    }
   
    // Don't forget about copy assignment operator
    Vector& operator=(const Vector & other) {
         if (this != &other) {
             for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                 components[i] = other.components[i];
             }
         }
         return *this;
    }
   
    // Don't forget about move assignment operator
    Vector& operator=(Vector && other) {
         if (this != &other) {
             delete[] components;
             components = other.components;
             other.components = nullptr;
         }
         return *this;
    }
   
    // Don't forget to free resourses
    ~Vector() {
         delete[] components;
         components = nullptr;
    }
   
    void print() const // const is important because static vectors are constant
    {
         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
              std::cout << components[i] << ' ';
         }
         std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    static const Vector ZERO;
    static const Vector UNIT;

    // Note, this instances of class Array are on the stack (not on the heap)
    template<unsigned int m, std::enable_if_t< (m <= n), bool> = true>
    static const Array UNIT_M;
};

template<unsigned int n, class F>
const Vector<n, F, true> Vector<n, F, true>::ZERO {0.0}; // define static const vector

template<unsigned int n, class F>
const Vector<n, F, true> Vector<n, F, true>::UNIT {1.0}; // define static const vector

template<unsigned int n, class F>
template<unsigned int m, std::enable_if_t< (m <= n), bool > = true>
const Vector<n, F, true>::Array Vector<n, F, true>::UNIT_M {m, 1.0};


int main()
{
    Vector<4, double> myVector {5.0};
    myVector.print();
    myVector.ZERO.print();
    myVector.UNIT.print();
    myVector.UNIT_M<2>.toVector().print();
    myVector.UNIT_M<3>.toVector().print();
    // myVector.UNIT_M<10>.toVector().print();
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
5 5 5 5 
0 0 0 0 
1 1 1 1 
0 0 1 0 
0 0 0 1
```